# Pattern stops working when adding pattern offset

Tags: regex, vim, neovim

I am trying to setup a couple of conceal rules.

```
" !== should be

!≡

" === should be

≡
```

I am hopping to capture `==` but not ! so that the end result would be `!≡` using the rule line below.

`au BufEnter * syntax match NotEquals /!==/ms=s+1 conceal cchar=≡`

However, "nothing" appears to be happening. If I remove the offset `!==` matches and correctly changes it to `≡`, but this is not the desired outcome. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
set clipboard=unnamed 
set mouse=a 
syntax enable 
set ruler
set encoding=utf-8 
set fileencoding=utf-8  
set iskeyword+=-
set t_Co=256 
set splitbelow
set splitright
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab 
set expandtab 
set smartindent 
set autoindent 
set laststatus=0 
set number 
set cursorline 
set showtabline=1 
set noshowmode
set concealcursor=nvic
set conceallevel=1

set wrap 
set linebreak 
set breakindent 
set breakindentopt=sbr 

nnoremap <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
nnoremap <expr> <up> (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <expr> <down> (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')

au! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source %

au BufEnter * syntax match Nequals '!=='ms=s+1 conceal cchar=≡

set conceallevel=2
set termguicolors
```

MCVE

1. Use above Vim Configuration in `.vimrc`
2. begin editing a new buffer without defined syntax highliting or filetype
3. type `!==`
4. Move Cursor from Line to see conceal

Expected outcome `!≡`

Actual outcome `!==`

Comment: Read `:h :syn-priority` and always provide MCVE along with your question.

Comment: @Matt Thanks I've read the syn-priority. I'm either not interpreting it correctly, or I don't understand it. This is a brand new install of vim, I've added my vimrc though for clarity.

Comment: Your example is wrong as you forgot about concealcursor.

Comment: I was setting it manually at the time and I took it out of my vimrc. It has been added to configuration above.

Comment: It does not work for me. I'm not sure why you're calling me lazy. If it did work I wouldn't post the question. My point above was that it was set manually when I was trying before I posted this, it was just not in my VIMRC at the time I posted this question. I've readded this to no avail.

Comment: Because your MCVE is neither "minimal", nor "verifiable". Even though you did it in a completely wrong way, but, at least, for _empty_ (i.e. no other syntax items) buffer it _does_ work (shows the concealed char). So either you haven't checked it ,or failed to check properly.

Comment: So I think it's important to note that some people are here to learn. As I mentioned, this pattern works until I add the offset to it. Then it stops working. I have uploaded a screencap. If I am checking, or doing something wrong please advise. Additionally If I am expecting the wrong thing please let me know. And If I am going about it in the wrong way steer me in the right direction please, or simply don't respond. 
https://gifyu.com/image/ZZlu